# How to upgrade Windows 8.1 32-bit to 64-bit without CD/USB

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

I have a PC running Windows 8.1 32-bit and I want to upgrade to 64-bit because I heard it's faster. I watched tutorials on YouTube but all of them require a CD/USB but I have none. How would I upgrade?

Comment: You can't upgrade from 32bit to 64bit. You need to do a clean install.

Comment: I plan to back up all my memory first then do that. But how would I do a clean install?

Comment: It’s not faster. Unless you have ≥4 GB memory, I recommend you do not do this.

Comment: Do you mean under 4GB or over 4GB because I have under.

Comment: @kprovost7314 >= is the sign for greater or equal to....

Comment: I knew that already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. There is no simple way.
2. Which is what you need.
3. The simplest way would be to get a CD/DVD/Blu-Ray+-DLRW drive.
4. A blank DVD.
5. magic-iso to burn your image to the blank DVD.
6. Boot from that and install as usual.

Sorry But that's the factsjack